# Insert other languages in phpmyadmin table row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to insert 1x 杜如風 風行風語 Lifestyle Book in one of the row in my mysql table. I am using Phpmyadmin for mysql data connection.

When i put that chinese text, row is inserted but I get 1x ??? ???? Lifestyle Book.

How can I get same chinese text? Is there anything to do with character set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the home page for phpMyAdmin, make sure that the MySQL connection collation is set to a character set that supports Chinese (a good choice is `utf8-general-ci`).

Comment: This would rather be on the home page, General settings dialog.

Comment: @MarcDelisle - Right you are. Fixed.